# SQL select MAX value or NULL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a simple table T1 that has the Schema

```
T1 (id NUMBER, val VARCHAR2(10), dat DATE)
```

considering that `dat` can be `NULL`

I want to execute a query to select the `MAX(dat)` of a specific `val`

or `NULL` if there's row having `dat = NULL` for the same `val`

for example:

```
id    val    dat
--    ---    ---
1      a     12-NOV-13
2      b     23-MAY-13
3      b     26-JAN-14
4      a     NULL
```

the query should return `NULL`      `WHERE val = a`

the query should return `26-JAN-14` `WHERE val = b`

is it possible in a simple SELECT query ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please let us know what you've tried so far.

Comment: well, its really complicated, I was trying to add a trigger for a table "Contract" in my project and noticed a bug, dat here should be the end_date of the contract, when it's NULL it means the contract is not yet ended and I can't add a new contract for the same val (or person), so my trigger checks only the max value of end_date and not the null value (not ended contracts) so I tried to simplify it with this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try selecting what you want, excluding duplicates, and then doing a union, similar to this;

```
SELECT VAL, MAX(DAT) FROM T1 
WHERE VAL NOT IN (select VAL from T1 where DAT is NULL GROUP BY VAL, DAT)
GROUP BY VAL, DAT
UNION
select VAL, DAT from T1 where DAT is NULL GROUP BY VAL, DAT
```

Comment: ok, but why you make a group by VAL, DAT in the NOT IN sub query? is it necessary?

Comment: No, its not strictly necessary, it just eliminates redundancy and I think improves performance, but don't qoute me on the peformance part (using "Group by" has a small hit, though I'm not sure if its more or less then searching the entire list, it probably depends on the number of duplicates you have). I simply wrote the outside queries first, then copied the last line for convenience.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you,I would use if clause for specific conditions
[this links is useful](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/loops/if_then.php)

```
IF dat <= 0 THEN
    returnValue := null;

ELSE
    returnValue := Max(dat);

END IF;

RETURN returnValue;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work

```
select * from (
select val,row_number() over (partition by val   order by  dat DESC nulls first) as row_num
from T1
) A
where row_num=1
```

Comment: Saw your answer after i posted mine. Yours has the same technique i used except you missed the order by to include DESC to make the max date pop out for each value.

Comment: @user good catch changed it but use row_number instead of rank, if there are multiple records with same date then rank will output both records but row_number will not

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT val, dat
  FROM (SELECT val,
               RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY val ORDER BY dat DESC NULLS FIRST)
                  rn,
               dat
          FROM t1)
 WHERE rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using analytic functions, if yo want the values on each row:

```
select t1.*,
       (case when count(*) over (partition by val) = count(dat) over (partition by val)
             then max(dat) over (partition by val)
        end) as StrangeMaxDate
from t1;
```

If you just want this as an aggregation, use the same idea:

```
select val,
       (case when count(*) = count(dat) then max(dat) end) as StrangeMaxVal
from t1
group by val;
```